# What is the pandas equivalent of the R function %in%?

Tags: python, r, pandas, iris-dataset

What is the pandas equivalent of the R function %in% ?

When we have a dataframe in R, we can check for which rows a column contains strings from a list using the operator `%in%` which gives a Boolean output.

**Concrete example:** If we want to check which rows the strings "setosa" and "virginica" are in the column `species` of the `iris` dataset, we can simply use the following code:

`iris[:,c('species')] %in% c('setosa', 'virginica')`.

How can we do the same thing in python for a `pandas` DataFrame?

The reason I want to do this is I want to filter the dataset and only keep rows with the species "setosa" or "virginica".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pandas` package has the `.str` method for columns that are strings and the `.str` method itself contains the `.isin()` method which is equivalent to the `%in%` operator in R. Further, as pointed out by @rhug123 the `.isin` method can be directly applied on a series. I have made the corresponding change to the code below.

Your R code above can be implemented in python using `pandas` as follows - assuming that `iris` is a pandas DataFrame:

`iris.species.isin(['setosa', 'virginica'])`

You can then filter your DataFrame and only keep the rows with species 'setosa' or 'virginica' as follows:

`iris[iris.species.isin(['setosa', 'virginica'])]`

Comment: you would want to drop the `.str`. `Isin` can be applied on a `series` or a `df`, but is not a `str` method.

Comment: Thanks @rhug123 ! Thank you for the your suggestion and great knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

`%in%` in R is actually `is.element`:

```
r$> 1 %in% 1:2                    
[1] TRUE

r$> is.element(1, 1:2)                                  
[1] TRUE
```

[`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) has ported some functions in R to python:

```py
>>> from datar.all import c, f, is_element, filter
>>> from datar.datasets import iris
>>> 
>>> iris >> filter(is_element(f.Species, c('setosa', 'virginica')))
    Sepal_Length  Sepal_Width  Petal_Length  Petal_Width    Species
       <float64>    <float64>     <float64>    <float64>   <object>
0            5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2     setosa
1            4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2     setosa
2            4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2     setosa
3            4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2     setosa
..           ...          ...           ...          ...        ...
4            5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2     setosa
95           6.7          3.0           5.2          2.3  virginica
96           6.3          2.5           5.0          1.9  virginica
97           6.5          3.0           5.2          2.0  virginica
98           6.2          3.4           5.4          2.3  virginica
99           5.9          3.0           5.1          1.8  virginica

[100 rows x 5 columns]
```

I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.